# How to delete files with a fixed pattern in Ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to delete files in a directory that match a particular pattern. Tried using the below code.

```yaml
- name: Find the machine yaml files
  file:
    paths: "{{ workdir }}/openshift/"
    patterns: "99_openshift-cluster-api_{{ item }}-machine*.yaml"
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - master
    - worker
```

However, when I try the above code, I get the following error:

```
TASK [ocp-config : Find the machine yaml files] ***********************************************************************************************************************
failed: [ash-test-bb8b-bastion-0] (item=master) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "master", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (file) module: paths, patterns Supported parameters include: _diff_peek, _original_basename, access_time, access_time_format, attributes, backup, content, delimiter, directory_mode, follow, force, group, mode, modification_time, modification_time_format, owner, path, recurse, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, state, unsafe_writes"}
failed: [ash-test-bb8b-bastion-0] (item=worker) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "worker", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (file) module: paths, patterns Supported parameters include: _diff_peek, _original_basename, access_time, access_time_format, attributes, backup, content, delimiter, directory_mode, follow, force, group, mode, modification_time, modification_time_format, owner, path, recurse, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, state, unsafe_writes"}
```

What Am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing up parameters from different modules. The [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameters)_module has parameters like `paths` and `patterns`, whereby the module `file` hasn't.

The message just reports the syntax error

> `Unsupported parameters for (file) module: paths, patterns`

and guides already to the correct one

> `Supported parameters include: ... path, recurse, regexp`

So you may have a look into [Manage files and file properties](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html) and the [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#examples).